# Concurrent mutable priority queue

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, concurrency, priority-queue

Is there a concurrent mutable priority queue? Ideally, I'm looking for a C++ implementation, but, for starters, a pointer to an algorithm would be very helpful.

To be clear, I'm looking for a priority queue where I can adjust the priorities of the elements. In particular, TBB's `concurrent_priority_queue` doesn't provide the necessary functionality. (For that matter, neither does STL's `priority_queue`, even if we ignore the concurrency.) [Boost.Heap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/heap.html) library provides serial functionality that I want, but without concurrency. Naturally, I'm looking for something finer grained than just locking the entire queue on every operation.

Comment: I suspect any such queue would either need a coarse lock or really many fine-grained locks and neither would be too efficient. But there might be another approach to your problem. What is your use-case?

Comment: Yeah.. I can't see quickly any way of doing such a thing reliably.  Is a futex/criticalSection lock such a big deal?  It can't take all that long to remove a pointer from one place in a tree and insert it somewhere else, (or move a pointer from one collection to another, or whatever needs doing in your priority-list implementation)?

Comment: Well, I was really hoping for a lock-free data structure. As for the updates, with the usual data structures they are pretty involved: you are not only moving a pointer from one place to another, but you have to rebalance a tree, or do a similar operation.

Comment: @JanHudec, as for my use-case, I have several priority queues that are being processed simultaneously and (hopefully) mostly independently. But sometimes removals in one require updates to priorities in another.

Answer (score 10):

A concurrent priority queue is often implemented using a skiplist, so Facebook's [ConcurrentSkipList](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/ConcurrentSkipList.h) may fit your requirements.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Thank you very much for the pointer. I only wish they had a documentation page for this class.